# React + Styled Components: How to write a dumb component with nested tags?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to extract a part of my markup into a styled component. How would I do this if my markup has nested tags?

```
<p style={styles.disclaimer}>
  By pressing enter you agree to the &nbsp;
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    terms of service
  </a>&nbsp;
  and &nbsp;
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    privacy policy
  </a>
</p>
```

To my understanding, styled-components are just native html tags with styles. But in this case I have a p tag that has anchor tags inside of it.

How would I transform something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: none;
`;

export default Button;
```

into that disclaimer component?

Comment: Which part? A little more detail would be helpful.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
const StyledP = styled.p`
  color: red;
`

<StyledP>
  By pressing enter you agree to the &nbsp;
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    terms of service
  </a>&nbsp;
  and &nbsp;
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    privacy policy
  </a>
</StyledP>
```

Comment: So is it an anti pattern / not possible to use styled-components to just make a `<Disclaimer />` component and stuff the text in it?

Comment: From what I understand, that would be beyond what `styled-components` aims to do.